# wxpython GUI and multiprocessing - how to send data back from the long running process

Tags: process, wxpython, multiprocessing, publisher

Trying to run a time consuming task from a wxpython GUI. The basic idea is to start the long time task from the GUI (pressing a button) and then, a static text on the dialog should be updated from it.

First I tried some threading (http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks and many other resourses seen), and I want to show back the messages using Publisher.class. It didn't went so well, after a message or two, the GUI seems to frozen.

Now I want to achieve that with multiprocessing. I have this method inside my 'GUI' class:

```
        def do_update(self, e):
            self.txt_updatemsg.SetLabel("Don't stop this \n")
            ...

            pub = Publisher() # i tried also calling directly from dbob object
            # Publisher() is a singleton so this must be useless?
            pub.subscribe(self.__update_txt_message, ('updatedlg', 'message'))

            dbob = dbutils.DBUtils() # DBUtils is the class with 'long time' tasks
            dbob.publisher = pub

            p = Process(target=self.do_update_process, args=(dbob,))
            p.start()
            while p.is_alive:
                wx.Yield

        def do_update_process(self, dbob):
            dbob.do_update()
```

__update_txt_message is a simple function what sets the static text on dialog.

Question is: how can I send back some text messages from this Process (just simple text, that's all I need)
Thanks guys!

Comment: After some more work, I end up with the right message in __update_txt_message method (connected to Publisher class). If I put print message.data it works, I can see it in the console. But it doesn't update the Static Text. So now the question is: how can I force the update? Still digging...

Comment: Why did you give up on using threads?  Generally, the best solution is to use a thread for the long running process and use queues to communicate between the main thread and the long running process thread.

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem now is using threads or Processes. I am able to get the needed messages in __update_txt_message but from there I cannot change the static labels, which seems totally weird. I can print the message to console, I can SetLabel and then GetLabel to see, ok the msg is there, but not on the displayed Dialog!

Answer (score 3):

Robin Dunn kindly answered me in wxpython mailing list

> The pubsub module is not able to cross process boundaries.  You'll need 
>   to use the classes provided by the multiprocessing module, or some other 
>   inter-process communication method, to communicate between the parent 
>   and child processes.

So I fixed my issue using threading module.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use one or more Queue objects to pass data back and forth to a multithreading.Process. It works more or less the same way with threading.

Here is an example: http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiProcessing

Answer (score 0):

wx.CallAfter(function)

Comment: Where this should be placed to? Inside do_update() method of the dbob object? What about function arg?

Comment: As far as I can see, CallAfter will help me run a function after the process work, but what I want is to get some text messages during this work.