# Can I run App.MainLoop from a Process using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, wxpython, multiprocessing

I'm developing an app which makes use of multiple processes.

Each process is created by the original python process (ie, there is one level of forking involved).

In order to gracefully terminate in the case of a subprocess dying, I would like my main process to monitor the status of each subprocess, eg:

```
while lifeIsGood:
    for process in processes:
        if not process.is_alive()
            lifeIsGood = False
            break
    sleep(1)

# forcibly reap the children
```

I would also like this app to present a wxpython GUI.  However, because of what I want the main process to do, I cannot make the blocking call `App.MainLoop` in that process.

My proposed solution was to run `App.MainLoop` in a thread of a subprocess (`Process` subclass) after forking.

However, this results in a greyed-out (nonresponsive) GUI.

Is there something special that I need to set up in order to run the GUI thread from a subprocess (post-fork), or is this not possible?

(<s>I'm aware that I could probably run the termination code in a separate subprocess, as the process list is created pre-fork.  However, having that code in the main process would be much cleaner from a design standpoint.</s>

This is not easily possible, as the reaping process must be the parent of any subprocess it wishes to query or terminate.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to keep the wx main loop as the main process and start the multiprocess stuff from within a thread. Thus, you get to mix threads and the multiprocessing module.

Check out the following resources:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiProcessing
- [wxPython non-blocking GUI threading AND multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935515/wxpython-non-blocking-gui-threading-and-multiprocessing)
- [wxpython GUI and multiprocessing - how to send data back from the long running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855363/wxpython-gui-and-multiprocessing-how-to-send-data-back-from-the-long-running-p)
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/03/python-concurrency-porting-from-a-queue-to-multiprocessing/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/51xEiNTn288